# How to define Parquet and/or Arrow schemas?

Tags: parquet, apache-arrow

Is there a language agnostic way of representing a Parquet or Arrow schema in a similar way to Avro? For example, an [Avro schema](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26161_02/html/GettingStartedGuide/avroschemas.html#:%7E:text=An%20Avro%20schema%20is%20created,and%20in%20after%2Dmarket%20documentation.) might look like this:

```
{
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "com.example",
     "name": "FullName",
     "fields": [
       { "name": "first", "type": "string" },
       { "name": "last", "type": "string" }
     ]
}
```

Is there something similar for Parquet and/or Arrow?

(I’d write this as 2 separate questions but Stack Overflow flags them as dupes, sorry).

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a canonical text representation of the schemas that you can pass to a libraries parse function and return the corresponding object, then there is no such universal representation.

For more context the representation of Arrow schemas for serialization is defined via [Flatbuffer](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/main/format/Schema.fbs#L555).  While Flatbuffers does have a plain text representation, to my knowledge I don't think any implementations of Arrow provide functionality to parse it or serialize to it out of the box (there was a effort to support this in C++/Python a while ago but I believe it stalled).  For testing purposes arrow has also defined a [JSON representation of schemas](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Integration.html) but this is not considered canonical.

Parquet's schemas are serialized as [Thrift](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/src/main/thrift/parquet.thrift#L1116) in a depth first traversal of the schema.  Similar to Arrow, I'm not aware of bindings that will take a parquet schema as [JSON protocol](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/concepts.html#protocol) and convert it to library objects in the target language.  Also given the representation is a depth-first traversal of the schema it would be fairly unfriendly for humans to read/write.

Answer (score 4):

If it's OK for the schema to be represented in a non-human-readable binary format, then yes it is possible to do this with the Arrow IPC encapsulated message format. For example:

In Python, create and serialize an Arrow schema and write it to a file:

```py
import pyarrow as pa

schema = pa.schema([
    ('field1', pa.int32()),
    ('field2', pa.float64()),
    ('field3', pa.string())
])

with open('schema.arrow', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(schema.serialize())
```

In R, read the file and deserialize the schema:

```r
library(arrow)

buf <- ReadableFile$create("schema.arrow")$Read()
msg <- read_message(buf)
sch <- read_schema(msg)

print(sch)
## Schema
## field1: int32
## field2: double
## field3: string
```